# How do I parameterize multiple countries in same framework in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng, pageobjects

I am writing a small script to test pages on amazon using page object model. This is easy if am only testing only the US website. I simply navigate to the petsupply page where I'll add more methods to perform search, checkout and other actions. BUT amazon has multiple countries with their own versions of the same petsupply page (different elements and xpaths). I want do the same test for for at least 2 or more countries (Australia and Canada for example) without writing a new script for each of them.
This means I need to parameterize the country and language and perform actions based which location is specified.

Its my first time using this site, please pardon my many words.
Also I have attached snippets of my code and repository here. https://github.com/ultrabeep/SampleAmazon.git
(Anyone can enhance and make changes as you wish). I will be grateful. Thank you.

[Eclipse Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ujpE.png)

Comment: can u pls provide the url for all the countries

Comment: Hi Sonali,
here they are..
https://www.amazon.com.au/ (Australia)
https://www.amazon.ca/ (Canada)
https://www.amazon.nl/ (Netherlands)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a system property as below

```
System.setProperty("cukes.country",System.getProperty("cukes.country"))
```

and in Runtime configuration, you may pass `-Dcukes.country` value

In config create the property file as per the country name.

and mention in driver class before passing the URL.

```
 String URL = Property.getProperty(System.getProperty("user.dir")+
'/src/com/qa/amazon/config'+Property.getVariable("cukes.country")+".properties","url");
```

and for common element you can manage it as usual way but for different element you may need to write switch case statement where in switch you need to pass `cukes.country` value and in each country statement you may call country specific method on those country specific elements.

Comment: Sonali. Your Idea sounds helpful, I will look at adjusting the code and posting my changes here for review and enhancement. Thank you